# Samba share is read-only despite settings

Tags: raspbian, samba, macos

I am running Samba on my Raspberry Pi, and have configured the `smb.conf` file [as such](https://gist.github.com/b4cf34a67f0ec3a1d3be8319e02024a2), which should just be the default version with the following appended:

```
[media]
    comment = Media
    path = /mnt/raid1/media
    valid users = @media
    force group = media
    create mask = 0660
    directory mask = 0771
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    read only = no
    follow symlinks = yes
```

However, when I try to connect to this share from macOS, it is invariably read-only. This never used to be a problem, but perhaps an upgrade to either Samba or macOS introduced it? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What's mounted at `/mnt/raid1/media`? Is it FAT, exFAT or NTFS? If it is then who owns the mount? What umask value did you mount it with? Hint: make the umask=0771.

Comment: @Dougie ext4. `root:media` owns it. Looks like the issue may have been a weird read-only mount done by the RAID manager (not sure why).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've upgraded something recently, the issue probably lies in that event... somewhere. It may be a permissions issue? Samba is both straightforward and arcane all at once, and it's difficult to pinpoint what isn't working with the information you've provided. Here's a short checklist of things to try:

- Does your shared drive have a valid entry in `/etc/fstab`?
- What `userid` have you set as owner of your share? (user `pi` is easy!)
- Have you added your userid to Samba's password database file?
- Are you connecting from your Mac with the correct `userid`? (e.g. user `pi`)

It's useful to remember that there are two sets of permissions that apply to your Samba share:

1. The permissions you set in your `smb.conf` file, and
2. The permissions you set up under your host OS (raspbian, I assume)

Both sets of permissions must accommodate the access you desire. If they are different, you will get the most restrictive of the two sets of permissions.

If these generic answers don't resolve your issue, I have two suggestions:

1. Take a look at this ["recipe" for Samba configuration on RPi](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FileShare.md)
2. Edit your question to reflect additional specifics & we'll look into that

Comment: Thanks for the tips. (Yes, I'm on Raspbian; I probably should have mentioned in the question text as well as tags.) As for your checklist: 1) yes, 2) root:media where media is a group I've created, 3) Yes, a user that is a member of the 'media' group. 4) yes, the same user as in 3.

Comment: Uff... I just tried to change the ownership of `/mnt/raid1` to `pi` (is that better practice than `root`?) and it complained about being a read-only filesystem. That's probably the issue.

Comment: Hmm, my comment got lost, but basically I sorted out the issue with the (software) RAID device only being mounted read-only for some reason, and this got resolved. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Noldorin: Good for you! Was the issue was an incorrect parameter in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Yeah I think so. I fiddled with a few settings and rebooted, but likely that.